# Safety script to clear cache and leave website immediately

Tags: javascript, privacy

I am working on a website for a women's shelter and they want a "panic button" that automatically takes you to another site. This is pretty common, but I need it to also automatically clear the cache, so the abuser can't hit the "back" button or history to see what they were looking at before being interrupted. Any ideas?

Comment: I think one way you could do it is to make a fake redirect page, add a script on it so that when the referer is X it redirects you again to a different page, but when the referer is not X then it looks like an actual website. Like a middleman page.

Comment: imho, it's better to just advise the user to use a private/incognito/pron tab (since JS can't clear cache/history). to stop just one back button click, use `location.replace(url)`, but that won't work across sites.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is "can't be done as website functionality" unless the user installs a browser plugin.  For example, here's what Mozilla Development Network (MDN) [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) about this:

> For security reasons .... there is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL.

Non-privileged basically means any javascript that a website might run on the browser.

Now a "panic button" plugin / add-on would be able to do this kind of thing, but:

1. The user has to install it.  (Simple for a moderately tech-savy person ...)
2. If someone looks at the browser, it will be apparent that it has been installed.
3. There is also the issue of people how people decide to trust a plugin like this to be properly implemented, and not contain nasty stuff.

---

A better idea would be to educate the user in using browser incognito mode.  However that still leaves traces on the user's computer (depending on your browser, and other things), and in external network logging, etc.